# Outlook COM Interop method event name conflict

Tags: c#, events, com, office-interop, ambiguous

I am using the Outlook com interface to automate the creation of emails.  I am trying to handle the `MailItem.Close` Event but the problem is that MailItem also has a `MailItem.Close()` method. I was hoping the compiler would infer that i was referring to the event since I was trying to attach a delegate to it, however that is not the case.

```
private void editButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    outlook.MailItem editItem;
    ...
    editItem.Close += delegate { editItem_onClose(editItem); };
    ...
}
```

The actual error is:
`Error  4   Cannot assign to 'Close' because it is a 'method group'`

and the warning is:
`Warning    3   Ambiguity between method 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem.Close(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlInspectorClose)' and non-method 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event.Close'. Using method group.`

EDIT:

my `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` NameSpace does not have the `ItemEvents_10_Event` interface.  I have `outlook.ItemEvents_10_SinkHelper` and `outlook.ItemEvents_10`  I tried to cast to `outlook.ItemEvents_10` like so:

```
var events = (outlook.ItemEvents_10)editItem;
events.Close += delegate { editItem_AfterWrite(editItem, editRow); };
```

but I still get the "events.Close is a method group" error.

Comment: Cast `editItem` to `ItemEvents_10_Event` before adding the handler?

Comment: How are you referencing the COM interop and how are you checking that the `ItemEvents_10_Event` interface does not exist? [The event should be there](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Hx8yo.png). Do you have a alias `using outlook = ...` at the top of your file, the lower case `o` in `outlook.ItemEvents_10` is very odd.

Comment: I added a reference to the `Microsoft Outlook 15.0 Object Library Version 9.5` using the VisualStudio add reference dialog.  as I type in `ItemEvents_10...` the IntelliSense brings up all possible options that would end my current statement and there are only two, the two I mentioned.  Is there a proper way to do either of those?

Answer (score 2):

You need to cast the mail item object to the right interface or class which provides the event or method. The [ItemEvents_10_Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.itemevents_10_event(v=office.14).aspx) interface provides the Close event and the MailItem class provides the Close method.

Comment: The namespace I have does not seem to have `ItemEvents_10_Event`, it has `ItemEvents_10` and `...10_SinkHelper`.  I tried to cast it to the `ItemEvents_10` like this: `var events = (outlook.ItemEvents_10)editItem;
            events.Close += delegate { editItem_AfterWrite(editItem, editRow); };`  and I still get the ".Close is a method group error".  that looks messy, see my edit above.

Comment: @MichaelBillingham The `ItemEvents_10` interface is the opposite of what you want, that is how you would force access to the `Close(OlInspectorClose)` method instead of the event.

Comment: That makes sense, where is the event?